# Turning rows into columns based on a value in excel?

Tags: excel, pivot, openoffice-calc

I have a bunch of data, ordered below one another in excel (actually openoffice). I need them to be consolidated by the first column, but so that all data are still shown:

From (actually goes until 100):

```
1   283.038 244
1   279.899 494
1   255.139 992
1   254.606 7329
1   254.5   17145
1   251.008 23278
1   250.723 28758
1   247.753 92703
1   243.43  315278
1   242.928 485029
1   237.475 1226549
1   233.851 2076295
1   232.833 9826327
1   229.656 15965410
1   229.656 30000235
2   286.535 231
2   275.968 496
2   267.927 741
2   262.647 2153
2   258.925 3130
2   253.954 4857
2   249.551 9764
2   244.725 36878
2   243.825 318455
2   242.86  921618
2   238.401 1405028
2   234.984 3170031
2   233.168 4403799
2   229.317 8719139
2   224.395 26986035
2   224.395 30000056
3   269.715 247
3   268.652 469
3   251.214 957
3   249.04  30344
3   245.883 56115
3   241.753 289668
3   241.707 954750
3   240.684 1421766
3   240.178 1865750
3   235.09  2626524
3   233.579 5129755
3   232.517 7018880
3   232.256 18518741
3   228.75  19117443
3   228.75  30000051
```

to:

```
1       2       3   
283.038 244 286.535 231 269.715 247
279.899 494 275.968 496 268.652 469
255.139 992 267.927 741 251.214 957
254.606 7329    262.647 2153    249.04  30344
254.5   17145   258.925 3130    245.883 56115
251.008 23278   253.954 4857    241.753 289668
250.723 28758   249.551 9764    241.707 954750
247.753 92703   244.725 36878   240.684 1421766
243.43  315278  243.825 318455  240.178 1865750
242.928 485029  242.86  921618  235.09  2626524
237.475 1226549 238.401 1405028 233.579 5129755
233.851 2076295 234.984 3170031 232.517 7018880
232.833 9826327 233.168 4403799 232.256 18518741
229.656 15965410    229.317 8719139 228.75  19117443
229.656 30000235    224.395 26986035    228.75  30000051
        224.395 30000056
```

This must be really simple. But I couldn't find it. I tried a pivot table, but that only allows me to summarise or count etc the fields, while I want them all to be displayed. Any ideas?

To elaborate on the pivot table. I put column 1 as row, column 2 as colum and column 3 in the middle, but that comes out with a lot of empty cells and summarised.

I am not sure on which search terms to look, unconsolidised pivot tables haven't provided an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussions with my collegues, this seemed undoable in excel. So I just created a short script to save each "run" (which is the first column) in a seperate file, from csv:

```
awk -F, '{print > $1}' rw.txt
```

Comment: It is doable, but it is better to use the right tool for the job.